# Changing cell content on google spreadsheets via api 3.0

Tags: c++, xml, network-protocols

I need to change the contents of a cell on google spreadsheets.

I have successfully gotten the data via google docs api (all required authorization and options tag are set).

But I can't change the cell content. I have generated the following url and data:

```
req url: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AnT0uFQJWw_edENkYndfQWxCWlVmeG9oNW5kWjhYVUE/tCdbw_AlBZUfxoh5ndZ8XUA/private/full/R2C1 
req data: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006'><id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AnT0uFQJWw_edENkYndfQWxCWlVmeG9oNW5kWjhYVUE/tCdbw_AlBZUfxoh5ndZ8XUA/private/full/R2C1</id><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AnT0uFQJWw_edENkYndfQWxCWlVmeG9oNW5kWjhYVUE/tCdbw_AlBZUfxoh5ndZ8XUA/private/full/R2C1'/><gs:cell row='2' col='1' inputValue='*match found*
имя: вася
фамилия: тра та та
номер телефона дом: +7123456789
номер телефона моб: +7098765432
город: москва'/></entry>
repl data: Response contains no content type
```

And sometimes I recieve "bad request" in reply.

i following [this](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#UpdatingCells) document when writing code, and create this:

**1. i getting cellsfeed url**

```
    NETLIBHTTPREQUEST nlhr = {0};
                nlhr.cbSize = sizeof(NETLIBHTTPREQUEST);
                nlhr.headersCount = 2;
                nlhr.headers = (NETLIBHTTPHEADER*)malloc(sizeof(NETLIBHTTPHEADER) * (nlhr.headersCount));
                nlhr.headers[0].szName = "Authorization";
                if(AuthTag.empty())
                {
                    string str;
                    str += "GoogleLogin auth=";
                    str += Auth;
                    AuthTag = str;
                    nlhr.headers[0].szValue = _strdup(str.c_str());
                }
                else
                    nlhr.headers[0].szValue = _strdup(AuthTag.c_str());
                nlhr.headers[1].szName  = "GData-Version";
                nlhr.headers[1].szValue = "3.0";
                nlhr.cbSize = sizeof(NETLIBHTTPREQUEST);
                nlhr.flags = NLHRF_SSL;
                {
                    string str = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/";
                    str += toUTF8(Params.vtszDocuments[0]);
                    str += "/private/full";
                    nlhr.szUrl = _strdup(str.c_str());
                }
                nlhr.requestType = REQUEST_GET;
                nlhr2 = (NETLIBHTTPREQUEST*)CallService(MS_NETLIB_HTTPTRANSACTION, (WPARAM)hNetlibUser, (LPARAM)&nlhr);
                if(!nlhr2)
                {
                    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::minutes(Params.Interval));
                    continue;
                }
                using namespace rapidxml;
                xml_document<> xml;
                xml.parse<0>(nlhr2->pData);
                Netlib_CloseHandle(nlhr2);
                for(xml_node<> *node = xml.first_node()->first_node("entry"); node; node = node->next_sibling("entry"))
                {
                    if(strcmp(node->first_node("title")->value(), toUTF8(Params.tszListName).c_str()))
                        continue;
                    bool found = false;
                    xml_node<> *id = node->first_node("id");
                    string spreadshit_id = id->value();
                    if(spreadshit_id.find(toUTF8(Params.vtszDocuments[0])) == string::npos)
                        continue;
                    for(xml_node<> *link = node->first_node("link"); link; link = link->next_sibling("link"))
                    {
                        if(strcmp(link->first_attribute("rel")->value(), "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cellsfeed"))
                            continue;
                        cellsfeed = link->first_attribute("href")->value();
                        found = true;
                        if(found)
                            break;
                    }
                    if(found)
                        break;
                }
```

**2. i getting cellsfeed to buffer for parsing on need**

```
                base_document_xml.clear();
                if(base_document_xml_buffer)
                    free(base_document_xml_buffer);
                NETLIBHTTPREQUEST nlhr = {0};
                nlhr.cbSize = sizeof(NETLIBHTTPREQUEST);
                nlhr.headersCount = 2;
                nlhr.headers = (NETLIBHTTPHEADER*)malloc(sizeof(NETLIBHTTPHEADER) * (nlhr.headersCount));
                nlhr.headers[0].szName = "Authorization";
                if(AuthTag.empty())
                {
                    string str;
                    str += "GoogleLogin auth=";
                    str += Auth;
                    AuthTag = str;
                    nlhr.headers[0].szValue = _strdup(str.c_str());
                }
                else
                    nlhr.headers[0].szValue = _strdup(AuthTag.c_str());
                nlhr.headers[1].szName  = "GData-Version";
                nlhr.headers[1].szValue = "3.0";
                nlhr.cbSize = sizeof(NETLIBHTTPREQUEST);
                nlhr.flags = NLHRF_SSL;
                nlhr.szUrl = _strdup(cellsfeed.c_str());
                nlhr.requestType = REQUEST_GET;
                nlhr2 = (NETLIBHTTPREQUEST*)CallService(MS_NETLIB_HTTPTRANSACTION, (WPARAM)hNetlibUser, (LPARAM)&nlhr);
                if(!nlhr2)
                {
                    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::minutes(Params.Interval));
                    continue;
                }
                using namespace rapidxml;
                base_document_xml_buffer = _strdup(nlhr2->pData);
                base_document_xml.parse<0>(base_document_xml_buffer); //memory leak ?
                Netlib_CloseHandle(nlhr2);
```

**3. i getting etag and edit url for needed cell**

```
                            string edit_link, etag;
                            using namespace rapidxml;
                            for(xml_node<> *node = base_document_xml.first_node()->first_node("entry"); node; node = node->next_sibling("entry"))
                            {
                                xml_node<> *cell_id = node->first_node("gs:cell");
                                char buf[4];
                                _itoa(i->row +1 ,buf, 10);
                                if(strcmp(cell_id->first_attribute("row")->value(), buf))
                                    continue;
                                _itoa(i->column +1 ,buf, 10);
                                if(strcmp(cell_id->first_attribute("col")->value(), buf))
                                    continue;
                                for(xml_node<> *link = node->first_node("link"); link; link = link->next_sibling("link"))
                                {
                                    if(strcmp(link->first_attribute("rel")->value() , "edit"))
                                        continue;
                                    edit_link = link->first_attribute("href")->value();
                                    etag = node->first_attribute("gd:etag")->value();
                                }
                            }
```

i using Miranda IM core network library in this code, and i think all right with network part, something wrong with request url or data content in request

**UPD:**

i have missed content type header in first code, now i fixed this, but have another problem, google returning "premature end of file"..., code updated.

**UPD2:**

i have solve this problem, it caused by wrong parameters passed by netowrk library, now i have following **Invalid query parameter value for grid-id.**, and does not understand what it means...

**UPD3:**

looks like i have misunderstand api, i need to rewrite some code, i will post result here...

**UPD4:**

i have tried to obtain edit url via different api function, but have same result ...

**UPD5:**

i have solved this problem, not optimal and i thnk slow way, but at least working, i implement few more api calls and addition xml parsing steps to get correct link for edit each cell, code updated if someone need this, rapidxml parsing library and miranda im core net library used here.

Comment: Just if I could come up with something just as expressive for the new Google Documents :)

Comment: @edgerunner what do you mean ?

Comment: I'm saying I wish I could find such a name for Google Documents as well. Unfortunately Cameron seems to have fixed [your wonderful title](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6486901/1).